# Django template loader behavior? (got Django TemplateDoesNotExist exception)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

**Folder Structure**

I'm currently learning Django from the Django book. I have the following directory structure:

```
.
└── mysite
    ├── books
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   ├── search_form.html
    │   │   └── search_results.html
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── contact
    │   ├── forms.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   └── contact_form.html
    │   └── views.py
    ├── manage.py
    └── mysite
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── settings.py
        ├── templates
        │   ├── base.html
        │   ├── current_datetime.html
        │   └── hours_ahead.html
        ├── urls.py
        ├── views.py
        └── wsgi.py
```

Where books, contact, and mysite are folders. I also have a separate templates subfolder for each of those folders to store templates.

**Story**

Now, inside */mysite/settings.py*, I have the following lines:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates').replace('\\', '/'),
)
```

Inside */contact/views.py*, I have the following line (note that render here is from django.shortcuts):

```
return render(request, 'contact_form.html', {'form': form})
```

However, the line above gives me a TemplateDoesNotExist exception. This is because the template loader looks for the file contact_form.html under */mysite/templates/* instead of */contact/templates/*.

Fair enough, even though I don't understand why that's the case. But, I have another case where it behaves differently.

Recall in the file structure above, I also have `books/views.py`. In it, I have the following lines (in different logical blocks):

```
return render(request, 'search_results.html',
                {'books': books, 'query': q})
```

and

```
return render(request, 'search_form.html', {'errors': errors})
```

If you look back above, search_results.html and search_form.html are under the */books/templates/* folder, not */mysite/templates/* folder, and yet the template loader managed to find those files. Note that it still works even when I move search_results.html and search_form.html into */mysite/templates/*.

So my question is, why is there a difference in where the loader looks for templates?

**Files**

Anyway, here's what my */contact/views.py* looks like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from forms import ContactForm
import os

def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            send_mail(
                    cd['subject'],
                    cd['message'],
                    cd.get('email', 'noreply@example.com'),
                    ['siteowner@example.com'],
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    print os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
    return render(request, 'contact_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Here's my */books/views.py*:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from books.models import Book


def search(request):
    errors = []
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        q = request.GET['q']
        if not q:
            errors.append('Enter a search term.')
        elif len(q) > 20:
            errors.append('Please enter at most 20 characters.')
        else:
            books = Book.objects.filter(title__icontains=q)
            return render(request, 'search_results.html',
                {'books': books, 'query': q})
    return render(request, 'search_form.html', {'errors': errors})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you apparently do have the app directories template loader installed, and since it works on your `books` app, I can only conclude you don't have `contact` in  `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: That was quick. :)

And yes, that was the problem. I still don't understand what INSTALLED_APPS does, though.

I'll accept your answer when the 10 minutes limit is up.

Comment: Well you would expect some kind of explicit list of python modules to run through the django framework (as opposed to random python scripts, all files in the directory, some naming prefix system etc. Explicit is better than implicit). PS: +1 for a very detailed question.